# How to use recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def reverse(str_):
        tot = ""
    if len(str_)==0: 
        return tot
    else:
        tot += str_[-1] 
        return reverse(str_[:-1])


print(reverse("chicken"))
```

The function should return the reverse of the old string. I cant figure it out why it isnt working.

Thank you,

Comment: Because you are not using `tot` in return statement in else section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change tot in every recursion of your function it will not have the desired data since you set it to "" every recursion. Try it like this.

```
def reverse(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    else:
        return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]


print(reverse("chicken"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to compare the "" for S. Just **if not s** will return true if s is "". The below code will work fine.

```
def reverse(s):
    return s if not s else reverse(s[1:])+s[0]
```

If you just want to reverse the sting and don't want to use built in method then you can use s[-1::-1]